# Move ctor and move assignment operator with non pointer data

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading, c++17, assignment-operator

I am new to C++ programming and here on the stackoverflow. I hope you will forgive me for my first questions here that are not so good written.

I am adding move constructor and move assignment operator in the class BigData.
Can someone tell me if they are written good?
Thanks a lot

Here is my struct Data that is used in BigData class. This is how I implemented these two methods.

```
struct Data {
    //...
Data(Data &&_d)
    {
        data = _d.data;
        _d.data = nullptr;
        size = _d.size;
        _d.size = 0;
    }

    Data& operator=(Data&& _d)
    {
        if (this != &_d)
        {
            delete[] data;
            data = _d.data;
            _d.data = nullptr;
            size = _d.size;
            _d.size = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
        unsigned char *data = nullptr;
        unsigned int size = 0;
    };
```

But now, I am not sure if I did it good. Since the Data is not the pointer I cant write the same thing as I did when I wrote the methods for Data struct.
Now when I do BigData bd2= move(bd1);
bd1 stays with data array... should I somehow delete it?

```
class BigData {
public:
    
            BigData(BigData &&_bd)
        {
            m_data = _bd.GetData();
            m_crc = _bd.GetCrc();
            _bd.InvalidateCrc();
        }

    BigData& operator=(BigData &&_bd)
    {
        if (this != &_bd)
        {
            m_data = _bd.GetData();
            m_crc = _bd.GetCrc();
    
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    Data m_data;
    unsigned long int m_crc = -1;
};
```

Comment: Why not leave all the BigData constructors and assignment operator to their defaults ? For such a simple aggregate class, it would work perfectly, assuming Data is implemented correctly.

Comment: Consider using the defaults (what the compiler gives you, unless you override it) for copy/move constructors and corresponding assignment operators.   You might want to learn how to use initialiser lists in constructors, and to use `std::move()` in move constructors and assignments.   Also, it is possible to implement assignment operators be creating a copy and swapping.

Comment: @Jeffrey I thought about it that I dont need to write it by myself here. But I was asked to make move ctor and move assignment operator for struct Data and for class BigData.

Comment: @Peter thank you. Well I got the code where all were implemented and just left for me the two one to write.

Comment: @newstudent - That may be so.   But if the ones that have already been implemented can be improved, it's worth considering doing so.

Comment: @newstudent "asked"? in an academic setting it makes sense. In the professional world, it then depends on the location. At a car sharing company, in California, you push back and you keep the =default implementation. At a financial institution outsourced office in Shanghai, yeah, you reluctantly implement it. (both examples from past personnal experience)

Comment: @Peter well I can't change the code because it is like task setting, I just need to add methods that will be reviewed. But I am wondering if I am doing it right, I want to learn.

Comment: @Jeffrey thanks for the examples. Yes it is academic setting and my two methods will be reviewed. So, is it the right behavior for BigData class to have access to data after I moved it to other object?

Comment: If I'm understanding my standards correctly, you only need a rule of 5 on `Data` and not `BigData`. `BigData` will get by just fine with what the compiler provides.

Comment: @sweenish I need it on both but I am not sure If I am doing it right. To be honest I agree with you but my lecturers want me to do it for BigData too

Comment: Then, as said above, use std::move() and let Data do the "heavy lifting".